# Distance between zip codes: Running into a 500 vector limit calling given function

Tags: r, tidyverse, distance, geosphere

In a helpful post from Dave2e back in 2019, I'm using his suggested function as described here:

[R Find the Distance between Two US Zipcode columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408526/r-find-the-distance-between-two-us-zipcode-columns)

Dave's solution works great for the OP.   My issue is:  When I feed the function more than 500 rows of starting & ending zip data, I get this error below

> Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2

Using 500 rows is OK!  But if I feed the function any more than 500 rows-- it throws the error above.

Question:  Is it possible to outmaneuver this limitation by re-writing the given function?  If so, could you please explain & guide the way?  Thank you!

```
library(zipcode)
library(geosphere)

#dataframe need to be character arrays or the else the leading zeros will be dropped causing errors
df <- data.frame("ZIP_START" = c(95051, 94534, 60193, 94591, 94128, 94015, 94553, 10994, 95008), 
       "ZIP_END" = c(98053, 94128, 60666, 73344, 94128, 73344, 94128, "07105", 94128), 
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data("zipcode")

df$distance_meters<-apply(df, 1, function(x){
  startindex<-which(x[["ZIP_START"]]==zipcode$zip)
  endindex<-which(x[["ZIP_END"]]==zipcode$zip)
  distGeo(p1=c(zipcode[startindex, "longitude"], zipcode[startindex, "latitude"]), p2=c(zipcode[endindex, "longitude"], zipcode[endindex, "latitude"]))
})
```

Comment: I've added an answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66683711/5977215) which should work on your data also.

Comment: Thank you.  Your recommendation worked great-- speedy & just what I needed.  Cheers, mate!